# Do I have to 'remove' and 're-attach' Magic Mouse when switching between Snow Leopard and Windows 7?

Tags: magic-mouse

I am deciding to buy an Apple Magic Mouse but I am wondering about the method which I have to use with Apple's Mighty Mouse:

**CASE 1: If I am using OS X and switching to Windows 7:**

1. Remove Mighty mouse from Bluetooth device
2. Reboot in Windows 7
3. Add Mighty mouse as new Bluetooth device in Windows 7

**CASE 2: If I need to switch back to OS X:**

1. Remove Mighty Mouse from Windows' Bluetooth device list
2. Reboot in OS X
3. Add Mighty mouse as new Bluetooth device in OS X

Do I still need to proceed in this way with the Magic Mouse or not?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The connection process would go on forever until the mouse just locks up. What I found was that you could reconnect to it in Win7 after you had... (wait for it...)

Removed and replaced the batteries to the Magic Mouse!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a duplicate of [Is it possible to pair my Magic Mouse to both Windows and Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/170717/is-it-possible-to-pair-my-magic-mouse-to-both-windows-and-mac-os-x/) to me. You should not have to unpair your bluetooth mouse (whether it is Mighty or Magic) from your computer when you switch operating systems.