# Is it possible to pair my Magic Mouse to both Windows and Mac OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, bluetooth, boot-camp

I have a Magic Mouse that I'd like to use on Windows and Mac OS X (scrolling will not be necessary on Windows, at least for now, since I have this shiny trackpad too). However, it is my understanding that Bluetooth devices can only be paired to one computer at a time and even to one OS at a time.

Is it possible to have my Magic Mouse paired to both my Windows and Mac OS X partition at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. While Bluetooth devices can only be paired to one computer at a time, most devices include functionality to "save" device settings, allowing for quicker setup.

For example, I have my Mighty Mouse paired with both my MacBook (running OS X) and my ThinkPad (running Ubuntu Linux). As long as only one of the computers is on at a time, I do not experience any issues.